# Change the size of a Frame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I would like to know if is there any way to change the size of a Frame? I have a Frame in the top of my website playing music and I would like to add a (+) button to expand it or something similar. 
Any suggestions or ideas?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: are you talking framesets or iframes? I would recommend using neither

Answer (score 0):

maybe this should do it:

```
$('button').click(function(){
  $('#frame').css('width':'400px');
});
```

where #frame is your frame id.